# Requesting tips in optimizing a SQL query

Tags: sql, optimization, indexing

I have a SQL query that appears fairly straightforward. However, it performs poorly in Production. Any recommendations for improving performance will be appreciated.

```
    SELECT  DISTINCT CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID,
       CUSTOMERS.FNAME,
       CUSTOMERS.LNAME,
       CUSTOMERS.CURR_STAT,
       CUSTOMERS.CREATE_TIME,
       CUSTOMERS.ROUTE_NBR,
    FROM CUSTOMERS
    INNER JOIN 
       INVS
    ON 
       CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID = INVS.CUST_ID
    WHERE
       CUSTOMERS.ROUTE_NBR = 'A10' AND
       ( 
          CUSTOMERS.LAST_UPD_DT >= ? OR 
          CUSTOMERS.CURR_STAT IN ( 'PRE' , 'POST' , 'REV')
       ) AND
       CUSTOMERS.CURR_STAT NOT IN ( 'START' , 'END' , 'REJ') AND
       (
          INVS.INV_CODE = 'AVL' OR 
          INVS.INV_CODE = 'ONORD'
       )
```

There is an index on the CUSTOMERS table on the following columns:

1. ROUTE_NBR
2. CUST_ID
3. CREATE_TIME
4. CURR_STAT

Would it make a significant difference if the index included the LAST_UPD_DT column instead of the CREATE_TIME column to reflect the predicates? Any other improvement that can be made? Thank you.

Comment: Are that index on all four columns or one index for each?

Comment: What database? What is the number of rows in the table?

Comment: Also is there any other `CURR_STAT` that is not on those 6 you used in your query?

Comment: @JorgeCampos There is a single index comprising of those four columns. And yes, there are several other values for CURR_STAT.

Comment: @ULick the database is db2. There are around 4 million customer records and around 2 million inventory records.

Comment: What indexes do you have on those tables?  What you mentioned -- is that 1 index with 4 columns?  Or 4 1-column indexes.  It makes a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only fetching columns from the `CUSTOMERS` table I would suggest to use `EXISTS`operation to remove the DISTINCT operation. It would be:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID,
       CUSTOMERS.FNAME,
       CUSTOMERS.LNAME,
       CUSTOMERS.CURR_STAT,
       CUSTOMERS.CREATE_TIME,
       CUSTOMERS.ROUTE_NBR,
  FROM CUSTOMERS
 WHERE CUSTOMERS.ROUTE_NBR = 'A10' 
   AND (CUSTOMERS.LAST_UPD_DT >= ? OR 
        CUSTOMERS.CURR_STAT IN ( 'PRE' , 'POST' , 'REV')) 
   AND CUSTOMERS.CURR_STAT NOT IN ( 'START' , 'END' , 'REJ') 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM INVS
                WHERE INVS.CUST_ID = CUSTOMERS.CUST_ID
                  AND INVS.INV_CODE IN ('AVL', 'ONORD')
              )
```

Also adding the Explain Plan of your current query would certainly help. And for your question `if the index included the LAST_UPD_DT column instead of the CREATE_TIME column to reflect the predicates?` Most probably yes.

But the exact way you know will be to get the Explain Plan of your actual create/change the index and compare it with the new explain plan.

Comment: Thank you, Jorge. I will modify the query as you suggested, change the index, and obtain the Explain Plans from the DBAs. Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

I agree Jorge about removing the `distinct` and using `exists`:

```
SELECT c.*  -- or whatever
FROM CUSTOMERS c
WHERE c.ROUTE_NBR = 'A10' AND
      (c.LAST_UPD_DT >= ? OR 
       c.CURR_STAT IN ( 'PRE' , 'POST' , 'REV')
      ) AND
      c.CURR_STAT NOT IN ( 'START' , 'END' , 'REJ') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM INVS
              WHERE C.CUST_ID = INVS.CUST_ID AND INVS.INV_CODE IN ('AVL', 'ONORD')

   );
```

Then for this query, you want indexes on `INVS(CUST_ID, INV_CODE)`, and `CUSTOMERS(ROUTE_NBR, CURR_STAT, LAST_UPD_DT, CUST_ID)`.

Comment: Appreciate your input, Gordon! Thank you.